# SSH takes long time to connect

Tags: ssh, password

after installing build-essential (not pre-installed on Minibian) it seems like ssh takes a really long time to connect. 
On OS X, when I press enter in the terminal, the text to enter the password would appear immediately. After installing build-essential, it takes between 5-10s for the password text to appear. Has anyone noticed similar issues?

Syslog entry with dhclient:

```
Aug  5 19:35:04 raspberrypi dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Aug  5 19:35:07 raspberrypi dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Aug  5 19:35:07 raspberrypi dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Comment: Any clue in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Will check asap and report back!

Comment: There is nothing about ssh or any related stuff in syslog, only some CRON entries and dhclient

Comment: If `dhclient` is having problems, so will your inet connection.

Comment: My inet connection works fine, I can connect to nginx no problem without delay

Comment: @goldilocks can you check out my edited question? I included the only things that dhclient outputs all the time

Comment: That definitely means `dhclient` failed and there is no connection at that point -- *or* if there demonstrably is, there's a screwy configuration (are you actually using `eth0`, i.e., ethernet, or wifi?).  However, it will be retried at fairly short intervals, which *might* explain the issue.  If you are sure there's a sound connection at both ends, I'd recommend watching this exchange with [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) or something similar to see exactly where the delay happens.

Comment: Thanks! I am using wlan0, eth0 is not connected. I will try to use wireshark and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a DNS time out on the rPi.  Check that `/etc/resolv.conf` is configured properly and that you can reach the DNS server(s) you have defined.

To read the contents of that file:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

To test a DNS query with your system's configuration:

```
nslookup stackexchange.com
```

To test a DNS query with an alternate name server:

```
nslookup stackexchange.com 8.8.8.8  # Google name server
nslookup stackexchange.com 208.67.222.222 # OpenDNS name server
```

If none of the queries work verify if any of them respond to ping (including the name server(s) you have defined in your resolv.conf.  If you are unable to ping them there's something wrong with your network settings (e.g. gateway not defined properly).

Comment: Thank you, I really had a unreachable dns server in my  resolv.conf file :)